# How to inject separate/different parameter for test methods?

Tags: dependency-injection, testng, multiple-instances

I can inject class field like this:

```
class TestClass{
    @Inject
     Handler handler;

    @Test
    public void test1(){....}

    @Test
    public void test2(){....}
}
```

But the field "handler" will be shared between test1() and test2(),and cause a lot of issue to me,so question is how to inject separate/different Handlers for test1() and test2(),like this:

```
 class TestClass{

  @Test@Inject
  public void test1(Handler handler){....}

  @Test@Inject
    public void test2(Handler handler){....}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestNG is doing the invocation so you can't add parameters like this or it won't know how to call your test methods. You will need to rely on your injection framework for this (I'm assuming Guice). You can either make sure your handler is not a singleton and define two different fields:

```
@Inject
private Handler handler1;

@Inject
private Handler handler2;
```

Or you could use annotated injection if you want specific instances:

```
@Inject
@Handler1
private Handler handler1;

@Inject
@Handler2
private Handler handler2;
```

Comment: Thanks,your solution is not what I want.Right now,I create a private method to recreate mocks,and put invoking ahead each test method.